# http webharvest tag not working with http-param parameters

Tags: http, webharvest

I am trying the below code in webharvest

```
 <var-def name="url">https://www.athome.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-athome-Site/default/Stores-FindByZip?</var-def>

<var-def name="urlResult">
 <html-to-xml>
 <http url="${url}" method="GET"  >
     <http-param name="Content-Type">text/html;charset=UTF-8</http-param>   
    <http-param name="dwfrm_storelocator_countryCode">US</http-param>
    <http-param name="dwfrm_storelocator_distanceUnit">mi</http-param>
    <http-param name="dwfrm_storelocator_postalCode">07054</http-param>
    <http-param name="dwfrm_storelocator_maxdistance">999999</http-param>
    <http-param name="dwfrm_storelocator_findbyzip">Search</http-param>
</http> 
</html-to-xml>
</var-def>
```

I get the error stating There was an error processing your request.

Screenshot of the error is [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI0Gx.jpg)

But when i define the url with all the parameters, then i get the intended result

```
 <var-def name="url"><template>https://www.athome.com/on/demandware.store /Sites-athome-Site/default/Stores-FindByZip?dwfrm_storelocator_countryCode=US&amp;dwfrm_storelocator_distanceUnit=mi&amp;dwfrm_storelocator_postalCode=07054&amp;dwfrm_storelocator_maxdistance=999999&amp;dwfrm_storelocator_findbyzip=Search</template></var-def>

<var-def name="urlResult">
     <html-to-xml>
     <http url="${url}" method="GET">
        </http> 
    </html-to-xml>
    </var-def>
```

Why we have this kind of differing behavior ?

Thank you !

Comment: I used Web-Harvest and can execute your first config file successfully. Can you attach the error screenshot?

Comment: Hi Shaochuancs, i edited my question to include the variable definition  in the first case and below is the snippet of the response 
<div id="primary" class="primary-content">
<h1>An Error Occurred</h1>
<div class="error-page-message">
<div class="content-asset"><!-- dwMarker="content" dwContentID="bcGxQiaaiEQjQaaadmhmcSb1l6" -->
<div class="content-text">There was an error procesing your request.  You can try searching below or click
<a href="http://www.athome.com">here</a>to return to the Home Page.</div></div>
<!-- End content-asset --></div>

Comment: Only in the second case where i have all the parameter in the url itself then i get the whole listing in the response

Comment: I can still execute your first case successfully. Can you attach the error screenshot picture? It's hard to read code in comment.

Comment: @shaochuancs , i have edited the post and included the error screenshot for the first time run with just the base url and other parameters defined using the http-param

Comment: I tried again and can successfully scrape the web page using your 1st case.

Comment: @shaochuancs can you share your config as i fail to understand why the same command work so differently for two users ? i will try using your config and see if i can receive a successful message. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, my config is exactly the same as yours. The one below "I am trying the below code in webharvest" in the question.